# CollapsingToolbarLayout recommended image size

Tags: android, image-size, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am making a small app (specifically with LG G3 in mind) and I don't know, what size should the image in CollapsingToolbarLayout be. The width of G3 is 1440px, so would a picture of that size in width be overkill?

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a small app (specifically with LG G3 in mind) and I dont
>   know, what size should the image in CollapsingToolbarLayout be. The
>   width of G3 is 1440px, so would a picture of that size in width be
>   overkill?

Generally, ImageView would be having height of 250dp to 300dp. It would look ideal in any screensize your app would run in. However, still it depends on how your app UI design represents to.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what about the actual image size in drawable folder, what is considered good practice for image size (width/height in px, size in kb). Thank you